# Problems merging multiple objects into a complex object for Morphia

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, morphia

I'm trying to merge these three objects into a single complex object:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private List<Event> events;

   // getters and setters
}
public class Event {
   private String name;
   private List<Gift> gifts;

   // getters and setters
}
public class Gift {
   private String name;
   private String recipient;// the name of the person
   private String eventName;

  // getters and setters
}
```

My goal is to save the Person object in MongoDB using Morphia and this how I want my document laid out. I've created a document builder, of sorts, that combines lists of each object.  Each Person gets a list of all Events, but can only receive specific Gifts.  While my document builder does create a document that Morphia can persist, only the Gifts of that last recipient (sort order) are inserted into the Events for all Persons.  Though for the correct Events.

```
public void merge() {
   for (Person person : listOfPersons) {
      for (Event event : listOfEvents) {
         // somePersonsGifts: a sublist of gifts based on Event and Person.
         List<Gift> somePersonsGifts = new ArrayList<Gift>();               
         for (Gift gift : listOfGifts) {
            if (person.getName().equals(gift.getRecipient()) &&  gift.getEventName().equals(event.getName())) {
                  somePersonsGifts.add(gift);
            }
         }
         event.setGifts(somePersonsGifts);
      }
      person.setEvents(listOfEvents)
   }
}
```

If I modify the code slightly to process one person at a time by removing the outer loop and having the method take an argument for specific index of the Persons list:

```
public void merge(int p) {
   Person person = listOfPersons.get(p);
   //...and so on
```

I get one complete Person object with the correct gifts.  If try to feed the this modified version into a loop, the problem comes back.  I've tried using regular for-loops and synchronized collections.  I've tried using Google Guava's ImmutableArrayList and still no luck.  I know the problem is that I'm changing the lists while accessing them but I can't find anyway around it.  I wrote a DAO that uses the MongoDB driver directly and it works properly, but it's a lot more code and quite ugly.  I really want this approach to work, the answer is in front of me but I just can't see it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You did not specify what your problem is, you just hint at it.

Comment: I've tried to reuse the same list but the problem doesn't go away.  I apologize for not being clear enough.  I don't want to add all Gifts to all Persons, which is why I have the conditional on the inner-most loop.  I want to add the Gifts that match with a specific name and specific event.  I strongly believe that the behavior comes from the fact I'm not copying the current somePersonGifts list when I add it to an Event but a reference to it, so the last values in the somePersonGifts list are the values held in the all the copies.  Thanks to everyone for their efforts on my behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
List<Gift> somePersonsGifts = new ArrayList<Gift>();               
....
event.setGifts(somePersonsGifts);
```

You add the gifts only for one person; if you want to aggregate all the gifts into the event, re-use the existing list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about MongoDB or Morphia but I suspect the problem is your use of the setters `event.setGifts(somePersonsGifts)` and `person.setEvents(events)`.   Your code does not seem to merge the existing gift and event lists with the ones you are calculating further in the loop, which is how you would want it to behave (if I understand the question correctly). 
You should retrieve the allready existing gift list (and event list too) instead of overwriting them with empty new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the method merge() is inside the list but I assume that since you are using the list events here

```
person.setEvents(events);
```

Maybe you meant

```
person.setEvents(listOfEvents)
```

Notice that you are adding all the events to each person. If all the persons went to all the events, it is unnecessary to have the events inside the person.